# How to automatically kill a shell buffer when the shell process exits

Tags: advice, shell-mode, kill-buffer

In `shell-mode` when you exit the shell process (e.g. by typing `exit`) the buffer still hangs around (with the message "Process shell<1> finished").

How can I automatically kill the shell buffer when the shell process exits?

**(1)** Is there a package available for this?

**(2)** How do I write the correct piece of function advice for it? Noticing that `'shell-write-history-on-exit` is called on exit I tried:

```
(defun leo-kill-shell-buffer-on-exit ()
  (kill-buffer))

(advice-add 'shell-write-history-on-exit :after #'leo-kill-shell-buffer-on-exit)
```

but nothing happens. What's going wrong?

Comment: Your advice function should take the arguments `&rest _`.

Comment: Please have a look into `shell-mode`. You need to have `comint-input-ring-file-name` set if you want to use `shell-write-history-on-exit`.

Comment: `shell-mode` tries to set `comint-input-ring-file-name` from the environment variable `HISTFILE` or if that does not exist it tries to set it to some defaults like `~/.bash_history`. The automagic setting did not work for me, but `(setenv "HISTFILE" "~/.bash-history")` before starting the shell did work. Nevertheless your add-on sentinel did not run yet.

Comment: Just to check, did you *confirm* that `shell-write-history-on-exit` is called?  That sentinel is set only for shells matching `shell-dumb-shell-regexp`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a process sentinel when you want to react to a process exiting. e.g.:

Refer to <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(elisp)Sentinels`

In this case `shell` only calls `shell-mode` when (and after) starting the inferior process, so we can use `shell-mode-hook` to add the sentinel.

As @Tobias points out in the comments, `set-process-sentinel` will clobber any existing sentinel for that process.  `shell` will always have a sentinel (exactly what it is can vary), and we can call it first.

```el
(defun my-shell-mode-hook ()
  "Custom `shell-mode' behaviours."
  ;; Kill the buffer when the shell process exits.
  (let* ((proc (get-buffer-process (current-buffer)))
         (sentinel (process-sentinel proc)))
    (set-process-sentinel
     proc
     `(lambda (process signal)
        ;; Call the original process sentinel first.
        (funcall #',sentinel process signal)
        ;; Kill the buffer on an exit signal.
        (and (memq (process-status process) '(exit signal))
             (buffer-live-p (process-buffer process))
             (kill-buffer (process-buffer process)))))))

(add-hook 'shell-mode-hook 'my-shell-mode-hook)
```

---

Alternatively, @Tobias has provided an alternative using `advice-add`:

```el
(defun add-process-sentinel (sentinel &optional process)
  "Add SENTINEL to PROCESS.
PROCESS defaults to the process of the current buffer.
Use this function with care.
If there is already a process sentinel SENTINEL is used as after-advice.
That can fail if the process sentinel is reset by some other function."
  (unless process
    (setq process (get-buffer-process (current-buffer))))
  (let ((old (process-sentinel process)))
    (cond
     ((symbolp old)
      (advice-add old :after sentinel))
     ((null old)
      (set-process-sentinel process sentinel))
     (t (warn "Cannot set sentinel %S for process %S." sentinel process)))))

(defun my-shell-mode-hook ()
  "Custom `shell-mode' behaviours."
  ;; Kill the buffer when the shell process exits.
  (add-process-sentinel
   (lambda (process signal)
     (and (memq (process-status process) '(exit signal))
          (buffer-live-p (process-buffer process))
          (kill-buffer (process-buffer process))))))

(add-hook 'shell-mode-hook 'my-shell-mode-hook)
```

Comment: No good. This deactivates the process sentinel installed by `shell-mode` itself, e.g., `shell-write-history-on-exit`. If the OP set `comint-input-ring-file-name` the method of advising `shell-write-history-on-exit` is the right way of installing the additional sentinel. (AFAIK)

Comment: Even if there is no `shell-write-history-on-exit` there is an `internal-default-process-sentinel`. But, if you just exit maybe you can override that one.

Comment: I've added `add-process-sentinel` which is hopefully working under all present circumstances for this question. Roll back or edit if you see problems with this add-on.

Comment: @Tobias, I suggest you write that as a separate answer?

Comment: I consider `add-process-sentinel` really only as an add-on to your answer. I would only split it off if you insist. Note, that I know that the current version of `add-process-sentinel` is fragile. It does not work for the general case where there is already a lambda as a sentinel. One could take that lambda and call it from the new sentinel, but I did not want to go that far.

Comment: I'll leave your code here if you prefer, but I think the mechanism for latching onto the existing sentinel is the actual interesting part, so I think a separate answer is warranted, as the two approaches are quite different.

Comment: n.b. The problem with that `add-process-sentinel` approach as written is that `internal-default-process-sentinel` (most likely) now has that advice persistently, whereas that may not be desirable for non-`shell` use-cases.  You want to be setting a new process sentinel and then adding (or rather prefixing) the original to *that*.

Comment: `add-process-sentinel` is what its name says. If one wants to override the default process sentinel one can use `set-process-sentinel`. In our use-case the default does not hurt.

Comment: Yes, I'm suggesting that you could `set-process-sentinel` with the new custom sentinel, and then use your `advice-add` approach to ensure the *original* sentinel runs `:before` the new sentinel.  That way the only function which is being advised is the sentinel for the shell process (as opposed to advising `internal-default-process-sentinel` which may run for other processes too).  i.e. an advice version of what I'd updated my code to do.

Comment: Wow, @Tobias & phils, what a teamwork here! Thanks for all the thoughts. I will test it out tomorrow when I'm at my dev machine again.

Comment: Both solutions work - I prefer somehow the second one.

Comment: @halloleo As per my previous comment, I would suggest rewriting the second one so that advice is applied to the custom sentinel rather than the generic multi-purpose sentinel, unless you want "kill buffer upon process exit" to also happen in arbitrary other scenarios.