# How to make 'term' close the buffer when the process exits?

Tags: term

When I press Ctrl-D in a 'term', the buffer stays open with the text "Process terminal finished".

How can I make this buffer close instead of staying open with this text displayed?

---

Note, this is similar to this question: [How to automatically kill a shell buffer when the shell process exits](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/48306/how-to-automatically-kill-a-shell-buffer-when-the-shell-process-exits) however the solution there didn't work for 'term'.

Comment: Are you running background jobs?

Comment: No, this happens with `emacs -Q`, run `term` (accept shell) then press `Ctrl-D` to exit it.

Comment: To test if a process is running, term.el itself uses:  `(let ((proc (get-buffer-process (current-buffer)) ...)`; finding the right hook is the hardest part. Does the sentinal stuff execute from the linked question about shell-mode, or not at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add your `(kill-buffer (current-buffer))` to the tail end of `term-handle-exit`, either with an advice or just create a new function by the same name (ensuring that the library containing said function gets loaded before redefining it). To see what triggers it, have a look at `term-sentinel`. To verify it's the right place, just put in a few messages and see what happens when you type `C-d` in the term buffer.

```lisp
(defun my-term-handle-exit (&optional process-name msg)
  (message "%s | %s" process-name msg)
  (kill-buffer (current-buffer)))

(advice-add 'term-handle-exit :after 'my-term-handle-exit)
```